# MySQL JOIN from 2 tables with same ID using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table like:

**product**

```
id | product_id             
1     55                     
2     56                    
3     57
```

**product_options**

```
id | product_id | options_value
1       55           88
2       55           87
3       55           89
```

...                          ...

I want to select all `option_values` from **product_options** where `product_id` from **product** is same with `product_id` from **product_options**.

After I select all fields from product I use this:

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value ovi ON (ovi.product_id=p.product_id)";

if(...){
$sql .= " AND  ovi.option_value_id='$value'";
}
```

The problem is: If I only got one `options_value`, it's fine.
but when I have 2 or more `options_values` the result is 0.

i want to select all `options_value` from **product_options** for all `product_id` from **product_options**

PS. Sorry for my english and explication

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please show us the WHOLE query and provide an example of the output you require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use right join with product_id

```
select p.id, p.product_id, po.options_value from products p right join product_options po on p.product_id=po.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join between two table using product_id as join key

```
select p.id, p.product_id, po.optional_value
from products p inner join product_options po on p.product_id=po.product_id
```

Comment: can you please provide your expected output